# Axios Instance Bearer token not updated after login without reloading - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

When I try to login to my react app it returns as success and saves it in sessionStorage but when I try to access the page which requires Bearer token to fetch data via axios it returns http 401 error.

But when I **reload** the page, then the result is as required.

```
import axios from "axios";

let token = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("token"));

let AxiosInstance= axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://myurl.com/backend/api/",
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token },
});

export default AxiosInstance;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `token` is being initialized `onload` so you have to call token in `config.headers["Authorization"]` on every request through `interceptor` so you don't need to reload page.

**Interceptor:**
Axios interceptors are functions that are called before a request is sent and after a response is received

```
import axios from "axios";

let AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://myurl.com/backend/api/",
  timeout: 5000,
});

AxiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
  let token = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("sessionData"));
  config.headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + token;
  return config;
});

export default AxiosInstance;
```

**UPDATE:** You can learn more here about [Axios interceptors](https://axios-http.com/docs/interceptors)

Answer (score 7):

I'll guess it is because you're creating the axios instance outside any of React's lifecycle

when you run your app and enter your login screen, it makes a Axios instance

```
import axios from "axios";

let token = JSON.parse(window.sessionStorage.getItem("token"));

let AxiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://myurl.com/backend/api/",
  timeout: 5000,
  headers: { Authorization: "Bearer " + token }, // on the first go token is null
});

export default AxiosInstance;
```

After you login, your axios instance still has a nulll token, you see, this code is executed once and never more, that's why when you refresh the page, it works, because when this piece of code is executed once again, there's a token in localstorage.

There's a couple things you can do but the easiest i guess it's to use Axios interceptors

```
  AxiosInstace.interceptors.request.use(function (config) {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    config.headers.Authorization =  token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '';
    return config;
  });
```

That way every time you do a request your headers will be updated (not sure if this is the best approach but it works)

Comment: I tried it and its working. I had a question that if there is no token and the Authorization is returned `''` will that cause any error.